# Why the red equal sign holds？

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, vector-analysis

$$
\bar{U}_{x, \mu}(y)=\frac{C_0 \mu^{\frac{N-2}{2}}}{\left(1+\mu^2|y-x|^2\right)^{\frac{N-2}{2}}}, \quad x \in \mathbb{R}^N, \mu \in \mathbb{R}_{+},
$$
and Let $\delta>0$ be small enough such that $B_{2 \delta}(0) \subset \Omega$. Let $\xi \in$ $C_0^{\infty}\left(B_{2 \delta}(0)\right)$, which satisfies $\xi=1$ in $B_\delta(0), 0 \leq \xi \leq 1$ and $|\nabla \xi| \leq \frac{C}{\delta}$.
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^N}\left|\nabla \bar{U}_{0, \mu}\right|^2 = S$$
I want to prove that for sufficiently large $\mu>0$, the equation

$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_{\Omega}\left|\nabla\left(\xi \bar{U}_{0, \mu}\right)\right|^2 & =\int_{\Omega}\left(\xi^2\left|\nabla \bar{U}_{0, \mu}\right|^2+2 \xi \bar{U}_{0, \mu} \nabla \xi \nabla \bar{U}_{0, \mu}+|\nabla \xi|^2 \bar{U}_{0, \mu}^2\right) \\
&{\color{red}  =\int_{\mathbb{R}^N}\left|\nabla \bar{U}_{0, \mu}\right|^2+O\left(\int_{\mathbb{R}^N \backslash B_\delta(0)}\left|\nabla \bar{U}_{0, \mu}\right|^2+\int_{\Omega \backslash B_\delta(0)} \bar{U}_{0, \mu}^2\right)} \\
& =S+O\left(\frac{1}{\mu^{N-2}}\right),
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: For the part involving $|\nabla \bar{U}_{0,\mu}|^2$, note that inside $B_\delta$, $\xi =1$and $\nabla\xi = 0$. So the integrand reduces to just $|\nabla \bar{U}_{0,\mu}|^2$. Then you can use $\int_{\mathbb R^n} = \int_{B_\delta} +\int_{\mathbb R^n\setminus B_\delta}$ to get the relevant terms there. Not sure how to handle the remaining integral over $\Omega\setminus B_\delta$. Do we know anything about $\xi$'s behavior outside of $B_{2\delta}(0)$?

Comment: $\xi =0 $ in outside of $B_{2\delta}(0)$

Comment: If we're considering $\delta$ to be small and $\mu$ to be large, how big is $\mu\delta$?

Comment: I think it can't be estimated.